# Search for information about Yamanobe-no-michi trail

Tags: japan, rental, japan-rail

We have plans to make a trip via Yamanobe-no-michi trail, Nara, Japan. But I can't get how to reach one of the endpoints of the path from center of Nara. Any guideline will be helpful.

And also we would like to rent bikes. The problem is I can't find such shop/service because we will be happy with tricycles. Also what is the case about return the bikes? Is it possible to leave them on the other end of the road or we should return them to the starting point?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll need to take a train from central Nara to the trailheads, which are a fair way out of town.  Tenri Station is 13 min by train from Nara, while Sakurai Stn is about 28 min, both on the JR Sakurai Line which has services every 30 min or so.  There's a [very detailed official PDF trail map](http://www3.pref.nara.jp/miryoku/aruku/secure/2278/map.pdf) of the route (red line) starting from Tenri (天理, page 1) and ending at Sakurai (桜井, page 3), but it's Japanese only.

[Yoshimoto Cycle](https://goo.gl/maps/2Fbej49PspxLDLHc9) (吉本サイクル), next to Tenri station, rents bicycles for the trail.  Per [this site](https://www.nihon-kankou.or.jp/nara/292044/detail/29204ee4590136298) (Japanese only), if you drop them off at the Sakurai station bike lot (乗り捨て *norisute*), they charge ¥1700/day; if you bring it back (店舗返却 *tenpo henkyaku*), it's ¥1000/day.

Answer (score 2):

For reference I would like to add two more links to the companies which offer rent a bike in the area of Yamanobe-no-michi trail. Sites are in English. At this moment the second site seems to be offline (or it is not accessible outside Japan)

[Nara rend-a-cycle](http://nara-rent-a-cycle.com/en/)

[JR Rent-A-Car](https://www.ekiren.co.jp/phpapp/en/)

P.S. As per comment the first shop is located in central Nara city.

Comment: The first one is in central Nara city, are you planning to bike all the way from there to the trailhead at Tenri?

Comment: @lambshaanxy, I see, thank you for the clarification. No, we plan to use bikes only for the trail. And unfortunately we will need tricycles or bikes with support (small) wheels :(

Comment: Sorry, I doubt you'll be able to find such bikes for rental.

Comment: @lambshaanxy, thank you for this update. :(

Comment: Please accept my answer (click on the tick mark) if it answered your question!